# How can I run a node with fluffy blocks enabled?

Tags: full-node, compact-blocks

Now that fluffy blocks (compact blocks) are enabled with release 0.11.0.0, how can I enable them on my node?

Answer (score 4):

Simply run monerod with the `--fluffy-blocks` option.

## Windows

Open a command prompt in the folder of monerod.exe, or create a .bat file. Type in the following:

`monerod.exe --fluffy-blocks`

Press enter (in the command prompt), or run the .bat file.

## Linux/Mac

Open a terminal in the folder of monerod. Type the following and press enter:

`monerod --fluffy-blocks`